# foreach в многомерном массиве

Tags: php

Есть массив такого вида: 
[image: kint]

Пытаюсь извлечь значения, но не получается:

```
$i=0;
foreach ($department as $drow){
d($drow[$i]['departmentID']);
$i++;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В переменной `$drow` у вас массив с ключём *departmentID*, и на каждой итерации значение в этом массиве будет обновляться:

```
$department = [
    ['departmentID' => 1],
    ['departmentID' => 2],
    ['departmentID' => 3],
    ['departmentID' => 4],
    ['departmentID' => 5]
];

foreach ($department as $drow){
    echo $drow['departmentID'] . '<br>';
}
```